# How redirect all web-site to other domain?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web-config

I have a test domain and it indexed in goolge, but it is wrong.

Now I need to create 301 redirect from all pages with all parameters to other domain.

I could to create action filter and create redirect on it, but it is wrong for me too.

I have known what it can implement in webconfig. But I don't understand how.

Do you help me please.

I try to use:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to main subdomain from test domain">
    <match url="^.*$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)uh261477\.ukrdomen\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://kitesurfing-base.com{R:0}"  redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule in your `web.config` for this redirect:

```
<rule name="Redirect to main subdomain from test domain">
    <match url="^.*$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)testdomain\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://otherdomain.com{R:0}"  redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: @Mediator: Rule seems to be simple enough to work, however I am not Windows based developer so can't guess why it won't.